# Why disabling Workflows to start automatically in SharePoint through ListSettings>Change a Workflow, does not work?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow-services

I had several workflows created in SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint 2013, and I needed to disable some of them before "Creating New Items" in bulk by using a Quick-Edit view, so they would not send e-mails/change values/or create new items, as they were supposed to do if the setting: "Creating a new item will start this workflow.", would have been enabled in the List Settings/Change a Workflow page.

I uploaded the new records with the quick edit method, and then I whent to look for a change that one of the Workflows that I left enabled... ...long story short: Workflows that were disabled, were running... All of them!!

Does someone know why if I disable workflows through the SharePoint UI,so they DO NOT get executed automatically when adding or updating items, they still get executed when adding new items or editing values. Or why the same setting does not seems to be changed if I open the workflow configuration in SharePoint Designer 2013? Do I need to make a change in SharePoint and through SharePoint Designer so the change is honored?

To clarify: If I uncheck the box that says "Creating an item will start this workflow." through the SharePoint UI. Then, save the changes to the list, then; however, if I open SharePoint Designer I see that the box "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" IS ENABLED!!!

Does it is needed to make a change in SharePoint and through SharePoint Designer so the change is honored?

Comment: I don't know if you are aware, but there is dedicated SharePoint site on StackExchange. Probably there you might get more accurate answers. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/